# Carrier sense threshold

Tags: tcl, ns2

I hope you can help me how I can set the transmission range in ns2.34, I have executed threshold program with distance  and I get the Rxthresh_ value but I don't know how I get the **CSThresh_**  value  ?

Comment: Google, ns2 CSThresh https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+CSThresh ... Example http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2005-January/046659.html ... etc. etc. a thousand hits.

Comment: I'm sure you do not have a look on the links above !!!

Comment: »» I'm sure you do not have a look on the links «« : Problems ? Wasn't the example usable ?

Answer (score 0):

---

From http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2005-January/046659.html

" How to determine CPThresh, CSThresh & RXThresh "

" In order to set values to them you put some thing like that in your
scenario_xxx.tcl file "

```
# Initialize the SharedMedia interface with parameters to make
# it work like the 914MHz Lucent WaveLAN DSSS radio interface
Phy/WirelessPhy set CPThresh_ 10.0
Phy/WirelessPhy set CSThresh_ 1.559e-11
Phy/WirelessPhy set RXThresh_ 3.652e-10
Phy/WirelessPhy set bandwidth_ 2e6
Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.28183815
Phy/WirelessPhy set freq_ 914e+6
Phy/WirelessPhy set L_ 1.0
Phy/WirelessPhy set debug_ false
```

---